# BASH Scripting "while loop"

Tags: numbers, range

Write a program using ‘While Loop’ that will accept 6 integers from user
within the range of 6 to 60 and will calculate the Sum of all the inputted
numbers. If the user enters any other value that doesn’t fall into the range of 6-60,
an appropriate error message should be shown, and the program should
ask for input again.

Comment: trying to learn from examples of scripts. I cannot find info on: a) how to make a number range ie 6 to 60 in this example.

Comment: `range=$(eval echo "{1..10}"); X=10;  for i in $range; do echo $i; done;`

Comment: You should reformulate your question in a polite manner. Mention on what specific problem you're asking help for. Indicate what you've been trying so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNTER=1
sum=0
while [  $COUNTER -lt 7 ]; do
 echo Enter value $COUNTER
 read value
 if [ $value -lt 61 -a $value -gt 7 ]
 then
     let sum=value+sum
     let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
 else
    echo "Error"
fi
done
echo The sum is $sum
```